# Free text editor with comment/uncomment shortcuts

Tags: shortcut-keys, text-editor, sublime-text

I really like Sublime Text, but since I use the free version, the popups are annoying me.

What I liked about it really was the **comment/uncomment shortcut key** independent of the file type.

Is there any good editor out there with these shortcuts independent of file type (cpp,py,etc).

Comment: Gedit has a plug in that might help you https://yaserxp.wordpress.com/2008/09/03/5-must-have-gedit-plugins-for-programmers/ see number 5 "Code Comment"

Comment: Vim with [NERDCommenter](https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdcommenter) or [vim-commentary](https://github.com/tpope/vim-commentary) plugins installed.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a ide called `geany`, for installing it type

```
sudo apt-get install geany
```

and after go to the `edit` menu and then go to `keybindings` menu and from there set
keyword for commenting and uncommenting the code, and then press code combination in the code it will work,[image]